# Package "YHAT"-Confidence Intervals

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, confidence-interval

Experts, hello

I've got a problem with calculating confidence intervals with the package **"YHAT"** which provides various methods to interpret multiple linear regression.
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/yhat/index.html)

Specifically, the "boot.yhat" function (which does bootstrapping of all the  metrics of interest plus also computes a Kendall’s tau correlation for each type of predictor metric, correlating bootstrap metrics with sample metrics) gives me  the following warning:

**message: In cor(x, y, method = "kendall") : the standard deviation is zero.**

I have tried everything but the problem keeps driving me nuts. I have a very simple regression analysis with 2 predictors and 1 outcome variable. Any help is greatly appreciated as I have spent the whole day trying to fix this problem and tracking down forums for help but everything has proved unhelpful.

cheers, Armin

Comment: *You* have a data problem and you are not making *our* problem until we can see the data.

Comment: You probably have `NA` values in your dataset, I tried using a simple dataframe containing NA values and I got the same warning

Comment: There's probably a simple operation to fix this but without your attention to the data deficiency, I predict (with reasonably high confidence) we will be closing this soon